# jQuery "on" and Coffeescript

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

In JS I have

```
$("#index").on({
  click : function() { // do something useful with $(this)....}
},"li.superclass");
```

How I can describe this with CoffeeScript?

Answer (score 11):

It's almost the same:

```
$("#index").on click: ->
  alert ("hi")
, "li.superclass"
```

Comment: Too many brackets! Get rid of the superfluous cruft from your code ,~)

Comment: I don't think you can avoid the brackets around the selector, otherwise the `.on` tries to operate on the string of the selector itself.

Comment: I would probably do it in two statements, caching the jquery object (usually a good idea anyway): `$index = $ "#index"; $index.on click: -> alert "hi", "li.superclass"`

Answer (score 4):

mybe this is you want:

```
$("#index").on 
    click:->
        alert "hi"
    "li.superclass"
```

but i think this is more clear:

```
events = 
    "click":->
        alert "hi"
$("#index").on events, "li.superclass"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use `this`/`@` in the handler, I think you're looking for something like CoffeeScript's fat arrow, which rebinds `this` for you...

```
$('#index').on 'click', => alert(@)
```

Note that you need to use `off` to remove the handler or it may not get garbage-collected. Backbone 0.9 introduced [a `listenTo` function](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo) that makes managing event handlers a lot more sane.